# Where is my mistake $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan x^n} {x^n}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2(n-1)}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2n} \right)$?

Tags: integration

I am trying to proof the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan x^n} {x^n}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2(n-1)}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2n} \right)$$

but I am instead getting

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan x^n} {x^n}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2(\color{red} {2}n-1)}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2n} \right)$$

here is my solution

$$I(n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan x^n} {x^n} dx$$

let $x^n=y \, \Rightarrow x=y^{1/n} \,\Rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{n}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dy$

$$I(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan y} {y}\cdot y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dy=$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\infty} y^{\frac{1}{n}-2}\int_0^{y}\frac {1} {1+t^2}\, dt\, dy=$$

switching the order of integration

$$I(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\infty} \frac {1} {1+t^2} \int_t^{\infty} y^{\frac{1}{n}-2} \, dy \, dt=$$

$$I(n)=\frac{1}{(2n-1)}\int_0^{\infty} \frac { t^{\frac{1}{n}-1} } {1+t^2}   \, dt$$

let $t^2=u \, \Rightarrow dt=\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$

$$I(n)=\frac{1}{2(2n-1)}\int_0^{\infty} \frac { u^{\frac{1}{2n}-1} } {1+u}   \, du$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan x^n} {x^n}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2(2n-1)}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2n} \right)$$

Can you help me spot the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you switch the order of integration you say that the primitive of $y^{\frac{1}{n}-2}$ is $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}-2}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$$ while the correct primitive is
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}-1}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$$
as can easily be seen from the rule $x^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{n}}{n}$.

Comment: You are right! Thank you.

Comment: No problem. A very cool integral I must say!(+1)

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in twitter!